# Opencv import issue in windows 10

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, opencv3.0

I have an issue with OpenCV in windows 10. Whenever I try to import OpenCV I get following error.

```
import cv2
 ** On entry to DGEBAL parameter number  3 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DGEHRD  parameter number  2 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DORGHR DORGQR parameter number  2 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DHSEQR parameter number  4 had an illegal value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Krishhnandu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 305, in <module>
    _win_os_check()
  File "C:\Users\Krishhnandu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 302, in _win_os_check
    raise RuntimeError(msg.format(__file__)) from None
RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation ('C:\\Users\\Krishhnandu\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py') fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime. See this issue for more 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Krishhnandu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try downgrading python to version 3.8 .

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.9 is very new you should go back to 3.86 and write this in cmd

```
pip install opencv
```

Comment: I believe it's opencv-python.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can find help here: [How do I install opencv using pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51853018/how-do-i-install-opencv-using-pip)

Then, try the following steps:

1. Downgrade your current python version to python 3.8. Go there for more informations: [how can I downgrade from python 3.7 to 3.6 in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54371847/how-can-i-downgrade-from-python-3-7-to-3-6-in-windows). You can also create a virtual environment with python 3.8: https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/26/python-virtual-env/
2. Type this command line in cmd: `pip install opencv-python`
3. Check if opencv package is installed: `python -c "import cv2"`

For step 2, be sure your pip version is updated.

I hope it'll help you =)