# downgrade python version from 3.8 to lower one in a given conda environment

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda

In one existing `conda` environment, the python is `3.8`.  Is that possible to downgrade the python version for this specific environment from `3.8` to `3.6` or `3.7`?

Comment: Yes. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I suggest using `pyenv` for this

Answer (score 11):

Check this,
Open your terminal and search for available versions using the following command.

```
conda search python
```

If the python version you are searching is available then use the command

```
conda install python=3.8 (0r 3.6 or 3.7 depending to your requirement)
```

This will change the python version in a specific environment.

Note: This command will overwrite the default python version.

I suggest you open a new conda environment using the following command.

```
conda create --name py38 python=3.8 
//This lines will create a new environment named py38
```

Now you can work into this environment without interfering with the libraries of the other environment.

Hope this will help you.