# How to downgrade the Python Version from 3.8 to 3.7 on windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-venv

How can I downgrade the Python version from 3.8 to 3.7 in my virtual env? I have to install tensorflow 1.14, therefore I'm trying to downgrade the Python version. Is there a command for it using pip?

Comment: why don't you create a new env with the specified Python version?

Answer (score 4):

You can install multiple Python versions and set separate environment variables for each version.

If you use Anaconda you can also create separate virtual environments with different python versions:

```
conda create --name myenv python=3.7
```

Or you can use something like [pyenv-win](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win) to manage multiple Python versions.

Comment: I cannot edit this as its not enough characters, however, the command should be structured like `conda create --name myenv python=3.7` without the `--` flag indicator.

Comment: @CodeSpent Thanks! Fixed it.