# Can't Install Keras on Anaconda Navigator

Tags: python, keras, anaconda

When I try to install on Anaconda Navigator I get this error and I can't use it. Im using MacOS. How can I solve this error.

[Anaconda Navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJbRl.jpg)

[Error Text part-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6k7uX.png)

[Error Text part-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeJY1.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand what the error code trying to say

```
keras -> python[version=>'2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0.a.0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']
```

means that keras will works on 3 kind of python.

1. Python 2.7 and lower than 2.8
2. Pytonh greater equal than 3.5 and lower than 3.6
3. Python greater equal than 3.6 but lower than 3.7

Since your python is python 3.8, it raises error.
I suggest you to downgrade your python trough this guide : [How to downgrade python from 3.7 to 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52584907/how-to-downgrade-python-from-3-7-to-3-6)

Comment: And don't be afraid to read the error message from your program since usually, the developer will include many information to help the user to debug the problem

Comment: If my answer resolve your problem, don't forget to tag my answer as the acceptable solution :)

Comment: What you said worked but when I import tensorflow and run on spyder it doesn't works. And it say "Restarting kernal". What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new environment with the python version below 3.8, then install Keras on it