# Why I cant change python version?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to set python 3.6 as default (instead of python 3.8)

The output of:     `update-alternatives --list python` :

```
/usr/bin/python3.6
/usr/bin/python3.8
```

the output of `update-alternatives --config python`:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative python (providing /usr/bin/python).



 Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/python3.6   1         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python3.6   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.8   1         manual mode
```

the output of  `python --version` :

```
Python 3.8.8
```

Why the default version is 3.8 and not 3.6 ? what can I do ?

Comment: Try this thread --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52584907/how-to-downgrade-python-from-3-7-to-3-6

Answer (score 0):

`update-alternatives` manages symbolic links inside the `/etc/alternatives`. To make it work, the executable you are calling must be a symlink pointing into the `/etc/alternatives` directory. Please check that.

For example:

```
/usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
```

and after that the exact java version can be managed with `update-alternatives`:

```
/etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.....x86_64/bin/java
```