# How to downgrade the python on macbook from 3.8 to 3.5

Tags: python, macos

I've tried several ways to downgrade the python3, including using pyenv, but it has the build failed error. I think it's probably because my python3 is in my usr/bin folder and I can not delete it. For the course requirement, I really need to downgrade python to 3.5. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: It is best to create a virtual environment with the required python version (e.g. 3.5) and leave the system python (3.8) as it is.

Comment: A possible solution may be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52584907/how-to-downgrade-python-from-3-7-to-3-6
There are many proposed solutions. I hope this helps.

Comment: you could try using anaconda as it makes it effortless to manage multiple python versions and their associated environments.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Anaconda to install the specific python version. like it:

```
conda create -n py35 python=3.5
```

Comment: yes! That's the way I choose!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, install `brew` if is not already installed. Then add it to user path by:

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
```

Once done Restart your shell:

```
exec zsh -l
```

Now Check Python is located where:

```
which python
```

Next, Go through following steps:

1. Check if you have pyenv already installed on mac OS.

   `pyenv --version` -- Optional since you already stated that pyenv is present at your machine.
2. List all available version for python:

   `pyenv install --list`
3. Install desired python version:

   `pyenv install 3.5`
4. Set python 3.5 version globally:

   `pyenv global 3.5`
5. Check again if python is located whether in user's directory:

   `which python`

it should be pointing to your `/Users/usrone/.pyenv/shims/python`
if not then set it again : `pyenv global 3.5`

6. Update your .zshrc

   `if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then eval "$(pyenv init -)" fi PATH=$(pyenv root)/shims:$PATH`
7. Restart zsh terminal:

   `exec zsh -l`

You can also read excerpts from [Downgrade Python version SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52584907/how-to-downgrade-python-from-3-7-to-3-6)