# How to fix python pip Segmentation fault (core dumped) response from virtualenv after installing python3.5 from source

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip, apt

### Background

Hi, my main goal is to create a `virtualenv` for a number of projects that use older versions of python, which are separate from the system version *(3.10.x).* I'm using PopOS 22.04, with all updates.

I can't even use pip because of this error. I also read around, but all of the solutions I read either output a log file, or some other indication of what went wrong. Whereas I have nothing but `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` in the terminal.

I tried doing the above with `pyenv` before this, but it had so many bugs that I got sick of it after 20+ hours... This is also my first time installing *anything* from source, but I did read the README.

### Exact steps followed

1. I downloaded and installed python 3.5.2 from source from https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-352/
2. Extract folder in `~/Downloads/`
3. `cd Python-3.5.2/`
4. `./configure`
5. `make`
6. `sudo make altinstall`
7. `cd ../../Desktop/`
8. `whereis python3.5`  `# outputs /usr/local/bin/python3.5`
9. `virtualenv my_venv -p /usr/local/bin/python3.5`
10. `source my_venv/bin/activate`   `# activates (my_venv)`
11. `python`   `# opens python 3.5.2 shell, not the system's 3.10.x`
12. `quit()`
13. `pip -h`
14. Response is merely: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`... That's it. no indication of a log file anywhere to trace it back, nothing. Trying to install anything gives the same response. I even ran `sudo apt install python3-pip`, and get the following answer for that:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (22.0.2+dfsg-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

### I also tried...

I also tried the above with python3.7.5, but this time I ran `make test` before doing the install.

It's currently showing this in the terminal: `running: test_faulthandler (1 hour 6 min)`.

And I noticed some people say it can go for a couple hours, but doing this can help find some issues, and patch them or whatever. I'll wait it out to see what happens, but...

### Does anyone have any experience in this / know what to do???

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52584907/how-to-downgrade-python-from-3-7-to-3-6 This answer includes the pyenv way, but also some alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue trying to install packages via `pip` using Python 3.6.15 compiled from [source](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3615/) on Arch Linux. For example, the following steps would result in `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` being printed with no further detail, regardless of the package to be installed:

```
$ <path-to-python-install>/bin/python3.6 -m venv test-venv
$ source test-venv/bin/activate
(test-venv) $ pip install <some-package>

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

## Solution

The solution involves applying [this patch](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv/issues/410#issuecomment-1125942002), originally posted by [Benjamin Peterson](https://bugs.python.org/issue27987). The patch modifies the object allocation code to use 16 byte alignment instead of the 8 bytes assigned by `pymalloc` that causes the segmentation faults. I believe this issue was fixed in Python versions >=3.7.

### Applying the Patch & Compiling from Source

Enter the following commands sequentially into your terminal to download the source code, extract it, apply the patch, configure the build, build Python and clean up:

```
cd ~
mkdir py36
mkdir py36/tempfiles
cd py36/tempfiles
curl https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.15/Python-3.6.15.tar.xz --output Python-3.6.15.tar.xz
tar -xJvf Python-3.6.15.tar.xz
cd Python-3.6.15
vim alignment.patch  # Use your preferred text editor
# Paste the contents of the patch, save and quit
patch -p0 < alignment.patch
cd ..
Python-3.6.15/configure --prefix=/home/<username>/py36 --enable-optimizations --with-lto
make
make install
cd ..
rm -rf tempfiles
```

A working Python 3.6.15 build with the patch applied will now be available in `~/py36`. Test that the `pip` package manager works as expected:

```
$ ~/py36/bin/python3.6 -m venv ~/test-venv
$ source ~/test-venv/bin/activate
(test-venv) $ pip install <some-package>
```

You may need to upgrade `pip` and `setuptools` if you experience some issues installing some packages.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

#### Pseudo-Solution

Another solution that only worked temporarily was to comment out the following line in the `pip` file (as mentioned in the same [GitHub issue](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv/issues/410#issuecomment-1061786348) where the patch was suggested, which cites [this French article](https://johackim.com/changer-la-version-de-python-facilement-avec-pyenv) by Johackim):

```
sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
```

To find the location of the `pip` file that is used by the virtual environment, run the `which pip` command inside the virtual environment, e.g.:

```py
(test-venv) $ which pip
```

However, this only worked temporarily for me, whereas the patch has been reliable thus far.