# Is there any way to downgrade my python and all the package to 3.8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, interpreter, downgrade

I install python 3.10 in my new laptop, i used python 3.10 for a long time and i installed lot of package on it, but i need to downgrade it to python 3.8 because python 3.10 cannot support a package, and i found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52584907/how-to-downgrade-python-from-3-7-to-3-6) but if i remove the whole python, it will also remove all the package, that mean i need to install all the package after i do it. Is there any way to just downgrade the python interpreter?

Comment: That won't work as the python packages are installed against the interpreter. But you can install [anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/index.html) that allows you to run multiple pythons in parallel.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use it pyenv for working with multiple python versions;

```
curl https://pyenv.run | bash
```

Look at the available versions;

```
pyenv install --list
```

Installing selected version;

```
pyenv install -v 3.8.1
```

for more details;
https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/