# how to downgrade python3.8.10 to 3.5.6 on ubuntu via the terminal?

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-3.5, tensorflow1.15, python-versioneer

In order to install older version of keras, tensorflow 1.10.0 is needed. That should solve compatibility issues with an algorithm I am trying to run. TO be able to install these older versions of tensorflow and keras and older version of python is required. I have tried to work with different algorithm using my linux system, terminal and have not been successful so far. I wish to know how to downgrade my current python version (replacing my version on the OS system or through a virtual environment) to python 3.5.6 or even 2.7.
The code I am trying to run is FSA-Net at https://github.com/shamangary/FSA-Net
I am trying to run the demo 'sh run_demo_FSANET.sh' after cloning to my local computer.

- I do not use anaconda. I use pip.
- I could not install Pyenv on my ubuntu.
- I also donot have brew I have qbrew, which does not follow with the other commands suggested at [How to downgrade python from 3.7 to 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52584907/how-to-downgrade-python-from-3-7-to-3-6).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to downgrade python from 3.7 to 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52584907/how-to-downgrade-python-from-3-7-to-3-6)

Comment: - I do not use anaconda, I use pip.
- Pyenv method didnot work as I could not install Pyenv on my ubuntu; 'pyenv' command not recognized. The rest I am checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have [multiple versions of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547554/multiple-python-versions-on-the-same-machine) at the same time. 
First, install your python ver (alongside your present version):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.5.6
```

Then create & setup your project:

```
cd your_project
# Create venv
python3.5 -m venv venv
# Source 
source venv/bin/activate
# Install everything you need
pip install {package_name}
```

That's it! You should be good to go.

NOTE: you did not specify what version of Linux you have,
so I assumed it's Ubuntu. But the process should be the same for the other versions of Linux also (just different commands).