# How can i make an executable file from Python project written on Windows 11 to run on Windows 7?

Tags: pyqt5, windows-7, pyinstaller

I just have build a PyQt5 project for desktop usage and i want this to run on Windows 7.
Using PyInstaller i managed to generate the .exe file and run it on Windows 10 and Windows 11 successfully but it doesnt run on Windows 7.

I want to run the .exe without installing python on the Windows 7 pc if it isn`t necessary.
Any ideas?

Comment: Why doesn't it run? What is the error? Try running the .exe on win 7 using the console to get its output and post it here.

Comment: I have made executables with pyside2 + pyinstaller, and they successfully ran on other pcs with windows installed. Maybe you've missed something, or a dll is missing.

Comment: The error says that the version of the executable file is not compatible with the windows version(7).
I didnt add anything , i just made the exe file from my project and the files contains the .exe and a folder with icons

Comment: Then that's it, its incompatible after all. The only alternative I can think is to build the application from a machine with the same OS you want to run the app. It may be a virtual machine, or the computer you're trying to run the application. Just install all dependencies temporarily on that computer, test if the code runs, and create a compatible .exe file. Save that .exe somewhere else, and redistribute it as a windows 7 version from now on.

Comment: I just found out that Windows 7 are compatible with older versions of python, (i wrote the program with python 3.12) and now i m trying to switch to python 3.7 , also i dont know what dll files are and how to create them if needed on windows 7

Comment: Well, if there's something missing, the python interpreter will probably guide you through error messages. Also, too bad, I didn't know about windows 7 supported versions. I provided insight based on what I've done so far on my personal projects. If you need to switch to python 3.7+, [good news](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/), pyqt5 seems to support on that version onwards.

Comment: I switched to python 3.7 but it does not recognize PyQt5 and i am trying to find the problem :(

Comment: If you have more than one python version installed on your machine, note that you need to install pip for every separated version, along with all dependencies on your code. If you want another alternative, you could try to [downgrade your python version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65533322/14956120) somehow, but that's beyond of what I can help.